# Tree structure - Fetch last level data from two tables

Tags: mysql, select, tree

I have data in below structure.

```
A
    A1 A2

    B  B1

    C  C1 C2 C3
```

These information transferred into two table named `group1` and `group2`.

`group1` has first level of data and middle level data.

`group2` has last level of data and middle level data.

ie

`group1`

```
 group_name    group_id
  A             1
  A1            2
  B             3
  C             4
  C1            5
  C2            6
```

`group2`

```
 group2_name   parent_id
   A1             1
   A2             2
   B              1  
   B1             3
   C              1
   C1             4
   C2             5
   C3             6
```

Now i want to get the last level of information under the group A.

My output could be

```
group2_name
A2
B1
C3
```

I can fetch the information level 2 by using below query.

```
select group2.group_name from group2 
inner join
group1 on group1.group_id = group2.parent_id
where group1.group_name = 'A'
```

How can get the above output?

Here is [SQLFIDDLE Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fdad9/1)

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this:

```
select
  group2.group_name
from
  group2 left join group1
  using(group_name)
where
  group1.group_name is null
  and group2.group_name like 'A%'
```

that returns all elements from table group2 that are not present in table group1.
Or (depending on how your database is structured) also this:

```
select
  concat(left(group_name,1),
    case when max(mid(group_name,2,length(group_name)-1)+0)>0 then
              max(mid(group_name,2,length(group_name)-1)+0)
         else '' end)
from group2
where group2.group_name like 'A%'
group by left(group_name,1)
```

here I am grouping for the first character of the string, and getting the maximum value of the numeric value.

Comment: How can i give **'A'** in where clause?

Comment: @DhinakaranPragasam pls see my updated answer. I'm not using parent_id but if your real data is like your sample data, it should do the work